# Doesn’t Google Spreadsheet have a function like Excel’s ‘Table’?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-tables

In Excel, even if you create a 'table' and add rows to this table, other cells will not be affected.

I would like to implement this feature in Google Sheets, but I couldn't find a table.

[image]

If there is no function or concept called 'table', is there any action I can take in the example in the gif below?

(1) When A10 is created by adding a row based on cell A9, values already exist in E10 and F10, and these values are pushed to E11 and F11.

(2) I want the values of E11 and F11 to rise to E10 and F10.

(3) When it comes up, I want the border line aligned with E11 and F11 to be created based on E10 and F10. (What this means is that you want to make it appear as if no rows have been added to other cells.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't "Insert cells > shift down" solve your issue? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/54813

Comment: @TheMaster What should I look at in the link you attached? When I opened it in the browser, it simply contained information about basic editor use, such as adding and deleting cells and setting cell width.

Comment: Select A9:D9. Right click > Insert cells >Shift down. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/54813 => Subsection =>Add more than one row, column, or cell=>  Item 4.

Comment: This works similar in Excel as well

Comment: I thought excel doesn't support shift.. https://superuser.com/questions/1446655/excel-insert-rows-by-shifting-cells-down-without-format-loss-change-defaul

Comment: @TheMaster Ah, I understand. However, I would like to share the Google Sheet I created with many people.

You can't tell the people who shared it to press the shift key every time they add a row (because an error will occur if they don't press the shift key).

Therefore, I want the function I mentioned to work by detecting user events in Excel's 'Table' or Google Sheet.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to have both tables on one worksheet and not have two worksheets with one table on each?

Comment: @TheGodofBiscuits Although the above example is about unrelated topics such as fruit and population, the table I am trying to create contains values that are closely related to each other.

Therefore, multiple tables on one sheet must be located.

Comment: @TheMaster So, is there any solution in my situation?

Comment: @bsjy 1. I never said press "Shift" key. The exact quote in point4 of documentation was `From the menu that appears, select Insert [Number] or Insert cells.
For example:

    Highlight 5 rows.
    Right-click anywhere on those rows.
    Select Insert 5 rows above or below.` 2. I'm also unfamiliar with excel tables, but according to @cyberbrain this is the same way excel also works. 3. If you need some custom procedure, you can listen to key press events in JavaScript through sidebar html, but it has very low profit-work ratio.

Comment: "I would like to share the Google Sheet I created with many people." - if that's just for appending data to spreadsheet you should think about using Google Forms. If you need to use a spreadsheet with users that can't handle it correctly, you will be better off with that or a small application (that can then export data to a spreadsheet if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

There is no-built in solution. The closest possibility is a "Filter" but it won't meet this specific requirement.

In addition, when sharing sheet with other people, you should definitly prevent any unexpected change or mistake (a keystroke made anywhere?) made by user that would destroy your formula/file : **add security on your sheet if shared**

There is some great work around for adding data in far better manner than `right click  + adding a row` :

1. from cyberbrain : Use of google form for pushing new data.
2. from TheMaster : `Right click > Insert cells >Shift down`
3. from TheMaster : custom procedure

---

I would like to add more design practice that allow you to avoid that.
You should have sheets for presentation purpose and others more data oriented.
For your example :

- a sheet called price
- a sheet called population
- a sheet for sum up data (with lock edit)

The data sheet with data can use the "Filter" as below.
[image: Filter adding and sorting]

The presentation sheet with ARRAYFORMULA
[image]